# WSO2 private PAAS on EC2 using "Ready to use AMI". "./boot -s" doesn't restart all services after reboot

Tags: wso2

I have successfully worked through the howto's and set up the environment using the ami-4e062c1c AMI using the supplied /home/ubuntu/private-pass/boot.sh script. What I have at the end is the Private Paas instance plus several other instances that it has spawned. In my case I only selected the ESB.

I shut down all the instances and restarted them later. To restart the services I tried using "./boot.sh -s" plus further previous instructions described in this document.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Start+WSO2+Private+PaaS

When I have manually started the services (as user ubuntu) and run the ./boot.sh -s script (as root) I find that the SSO is not running on https://[ paas IP ]:9445/samlsso.

If I reboot and only run the ./boot.sh -s script then, comparing a fresh install with the rebooted instance, the following processes are not running.

1. The Hadoop process ending in "/home/ubuntu/private-paas/install/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar:/home/ubuntu/private-p"
2. /home/ubuntu/private-paas/install/wso2is-5.0.0/bin/wso2server.sh -DportOffset=2
3. The process begining with, "/opt/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java -Dcarbon.home=/home/ubuntu/private-paas/install/wso2is-5.0.0"

I suspect (3) is started by (2).

Is the boot.sh script intended to start these missing services too? If not what is the exact procedure for restarting an instance to get the SSO service working too? Is there an init.d script that exists or can be made available?

Comment: I made a discovery while running the boot.sh script in debug mode. The conf.sh file that is created on first run and then read read by boot.sh contains switches like, "y" and "n". The boot.sh file expects switches to be either "true" or "false". I made the boot.sh script tolerant of this by replacing the tests with a regex. `sed -i 's/=\+ "false"/=~ ^(n|false)$/g;s/=\+ "true"/=~ ^(y|true)$/g' boot.sh`. Now I can restart the main PAAS, but still can't get any life out of any of the spawned instances if I reboot them. So I am a bit further along the way to getting a usable system than I was.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to restart the complete PaaS deployment you need to execute the clean.sh. Please refer the below page for detailed information on this:

*If you make a mistake during the confirmation, use the clean.sh  script to reset the configuration before running the boot.sh  script again. When clean.sh is run to remove the current installation and prepare for a re-install, deleting the MySQL database information requires entering the default mysql username and password which are root/mysql.*

https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Quick+Start+Guide

Comment: The requirement is to restart an existing deployment safely after a host reboot.

Comment: Also, doesn't running the ./clean.sh script erase all configuration and data of the Paas Deployment?

Comment: Yes it does, clean.sh will remove all the configuration and data. You can open the clean.sh file and see what it actually does.